# Angular Material - Get value of one column for a mat-table using a service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-services

**Situation**

I have a table filled with data from interface A. But one of the columns should be filled with filtered data of interface B based on id of interface A.

**What I tried**

html:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    ...
    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getValueOfInterfaceB(element.id)}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    ...
</mat-table>
```

ts:

```
getValueOfInterfaceB(id: number){
    let filter: any = {Id: id}
    this.entrieService.getEntries(filter).subscribe((entries: Entry[]) => {
        console.log(entries);
    })
}
```

**Problem**

If I run the application these lines will be executed over and over. How would I solve this if I do not want to run the code over and over?

---

**Edit**: Errors getting while trying solution of @Eliseo

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'res'.
res[] => {

error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
res[] => {

error TS1005: ',' expected.
res[] => {

error TS18004: No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'res'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.
res.forEach((value,index)=>{

error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
res.forEach((value,index)=>{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better add a new property to an array of object than call a function in the .html. If the "calculated column" go from an API, you should create an array of subscriptions (use map) and using forkJoin subscribe to the array of obs

I imagine you has an array of data `[{Id:0},{Id:1}....]`

you make something like

```
//create an array of obs
const obs$[]=this.dataarray.map(x=>this.entrieService.getEntries({Id:x.id})
//subscribe to forkJoin
forkJoin(obs).subscribe(res[]=>{
    //in res[0] you has the response to this.entrieService.getEntries({Id:0})
    //in res[1] you has the response to this.entrieService.getEntries({Id:1})
    ...
    //so you can iterate using forEach and index and make some like
    res.forEach((value,index)=>{
        this.dataarray[index].newProperty=value
    })
}
```

Then create the dataSource. Remember, if you has a complex "column calculate", calcule the column only one time in ngOnInit

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I tried to use this as a solution but when I try to implement the code example I will get the issues you can see added on my inital post.

What am I missing?

Comment: sorry, is `subscribe((res:any[])=>{...})`

Comment: I choose this solution which also helped me to solve another problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it that way:

```
entries: Entry[] = [];
getValueOfInterfaceB(id: number){
   if (this.entries.length)
        return entries;

    let filter: any = {Id: id}
    this.entrieService.getEntries(filter).subscribe((entries: Entry[]) => {
       this.entries = entries;
        console.log(entries);
    })
}
```

additionally you can add async pipe in html

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    ...
    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getValueOfInterfaceB(element.id) | async }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    ...
</mat-table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Maybe I did not understand it fully but in the mentioned example entries would be field by the first element of the datasource and thereafter wouldn't be called again for any other element because of 'if(this.entries.length)' would then be always true. Or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: `if(this.entries.length)` is for, to have data from service/async call only once. it's completely optional if you want data to be updated in every iteration.